# The animation looks really slow in the rendered video

Tags: rendering, animation, armature

I am rendering some `Skeleton Anim (.psa)` animations with the *Eevee* engine but the animations in the rendered video looks like it's in slow motion, the character is doing its moves very slowly. The animations are from a game and they are looking very unnatural as they are rendered now.

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

> CPU: i7-6700HQ, RAM: 8GB, GPU: Nvidia GTX 960m

Can it be because of system specs?

Render settings: resolution: 720x800

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the distance between the `keyframes`.

After scaling them down, the animation looks fluid.

To scale up or down keyframes, in the `Dope Sheet`, select all of your keyframes press `S` and use the mouse to resize the length of your animation.